# In Django is it a good practice to always have a foreign key relationship to the built-in User or to the custom-built UserProfile class?

Tags: django, django-models

I know it's very standard to extend Django's `User` class with your own `UserProfile` class that has a foreign key to `User`.

When I start building other classes that refers to "users", should I have it point to `User` or `UserProfile`?

Conceptually it seems to make sense to point to `User` since that is the actual object and `UserProfile` is almost like the (extra) description for that `User`.

But in practicality, it also makes sense to point to `UserProfile` since it's easier to get more user information (address, phone number, or whatever other custom fields you have).

What do you guys normally do?

Comment: Since Django automatically builds a backwards relationship whenever a ForeignKey is involved (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects), there is really no point in linking to the Profile if you mean the User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always `User`. It's illogically to tie something to a `UserProfile` which is abstract in meaning. A person, for example, is not a profile, they're a user. It's an instant [WTF](http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m) whenever I see someone creating a relationship to `UserProfile`.

Comment: Always. But not always. I'm working on an application which has an Employee model as the user profile. Sometimes an employee will be allowed to access the application, sometimes she won't (i.e. the first has a corresponding User, the other doesn't). But I still need to be able to assign a task to any employee, so it only makes sense to link a Task to an Employee and not to a User. So yes, in _most_ cases you should link to User.

Comment: @roam: That is fine, and strictly speaking, in that scenario you're dealing with more of a subclass than an extension. It's subtle, since the setup is technically the same, but an `Employee` *is-a* `User` (at least in some circumstances), but a `UserProfile` is not a `User`.